# passing C format to nodejs buffer

Tags: javascript, c, hardware-interface

I'm trying to use a blinkm led from node.js using the node i2c-bus package.

The problem I'm having is that the blinkm expects the color of the led to be set using the format
`{'n',R,G,B}`, which will actually be `{'n',0xff,0xee,0x30}`.

Using the i2c-bus, I am passing the above format as a buffer, so in node, I have written this function to take an rgb object and return it as a buffer in the correct format

```
function formatBuffer(val) {
   return new Buffer({'n', val.r , val.g, val.b});
}
```

and then call it with

```
formatBuffer({r:0xff, g:0xee, b:0x30});
```

unfortunately, this returns an error `unexpected token ,` which I'm assuming is the first comma after then 'n'.

I've tried wrapping the value in a string, which doesn't through the error, but also doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions on how I can get around this and pass the right format through javascript to the blinkm led?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `{ 'n', val.r , val.g, val.b }` is not object format (lack of key). Change to array `[0x6e, val.r , val.g, val.b]` or `{ 'key1': 0x6e, 'key2': val.r , 'key3': val.g, 'key4': val.b }`

Comment: unfortunately, that won't work. The blinkm chip expects the format provided as per the datasheet `{‘n’,R,G,B}` I understand it is not valid javascript, which is why I'm trying to figure out how to encode it to be accepted.

Comment: The blinkm datasheet said: **Each command below is listed with its “format” overview.  This “format” is similar to how byte 
arrays are defined in Java (e.g. Processing) and C (e.g. Arduino).** Maybe you should try [ 0x6e, val.r , val.g, val.b ]

Comment: my apologies, I missed that statement. I will try later when I'm with the hardware again.

Comment: though I still haven't got this working, it has resolved the error, so I'm going to assume you are correct.